# Getting all positions of bit 1 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have provided binary for example, `01001`, and would like to get positions of bit 1, so I expect it will return me `[0, 3]`.

Is there any function provided by javascript to get all positions of bit 1?

Comment: With your reputation, you should know, you have to share your efforts

Comment: Is your "binary" a `Number` `9`, or a string `"01001"`?

Comment: LOL I am looking whether there is function out there. I have been researching for it but no luck yet.

Comment: *Is there any function provided by javascript to get all positions of bit 1?* **No**. you will have to write one yourself.

Comment: @Liam ok this should answer it.

Comment: To be fair to Rendy, he didn't ask for code and did just ask a simple question. It made me think and I enjoyed looking up a quick answer. Part of the reason I am on SO is to learn new things as well as help, so sometimes I don't mind putting in a bit of extra effort to supply code to a question.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: `just ask a simple question` there is something as a question being _too_ simple, though. It might be an OK question for a newcomer, but I don't think it's a good question coming from an experienced member. The downvote title text says "does not show research effort" and indeed - a quick trip to the API documentation would have actually answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a number, convert it to a string before hand, if it is a string you can do:

```
positionArray = [];
binary.split('');

for (i = 0; i < binary.length; i++){
  if (binary[i] == "1"){
    positionArray.push(i);
  }
}

return positionArray;
```

What i'm essentially doing is converting the string to an array (or number to a string to an array) of characters and then going through each entry to find the positions of each '1'.

Not sure you can do it this way with numbers, which is why I suggested converting it to a string before hand. It's just a rough solution and I bet there are much better ways of doing it but hope it helps.

Comment: Please let OP share some effort.  We are here to help and not code for someone else

Answer (score 1):

@DibsyJr has a nice solution if you are dealing with strings. However if you start from a number, then converting it to a string is an unnecessary overhead. You can do it efficiently with this function:

```
function get_idxs(x) {
    var arr = [];
    var idx = 0;
    while (x) {
        if (x & 1) {
            arr.push(idx);
        }
        idx++;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return arr;
}

> get_idxs(0b1001);
[0, 3]
```

**WARNING:** It does not work for negative numbers. Unfortunately for negative numbers the answer to the question depends on the underlying cpu architecture.

Comment: This is nice! Does it work with negative numbers? ( Does that matter though?! :-) )

Comment: @sifriday It does not work for negative numbers. Yes, it matters. For negative numbers the answer depends on the architecture and the representation of negative numbers. For example on x64 the internal representation of `-1` is 64 binary `1...`. But on x86 it is 32 binary `1...` so you would get a different result. Also note that on x86 `(-1 >> 1) == -1` (because `>>` operator preserves the sign) and the loop never ends. We could force it to quit on `-1` but still the answer depends on the underlying arch.

Answer (score 1):

MDN has a useful piece of code that works numerically and will take a number like 9 or in binary `0b1001` and return you an array with true/false values depending on whether or not the corresponding bit is set in the input value. For 1001 it returns `[true, false, false, true]`

You can then use this array to create your desired output by checking which indexes are true, and getting `[0,3]`

The MDN snippet is here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Reverse_algorithm_an_array_of_booleans_from_a_mask

And a quick example of using it is here:

https://repl.it/DuEh/5